# Video lecture for charts on modular curves

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, modular-forms

I'm reading Diamond and Shurman's *A First Course in Modular Forms*, and I just can't seem to wrap my head around the construction of charts at elliptic points on a modular curve, and the proof that the various transition maps are biholomorphic.

I think that a video lecture could be helpful for getting the geometric picture. Does anyone know of a good video reference on the Riemann surfaces perspective on modular curves?